# Return orginal background after Jquery changed it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have HTML like:

```
#bg {background:#fff url(img.png)}
```

I use Jquery to remove background of `#bg` id like

```
$('#remove-bg').click(function (){
$('#bg').css({'background':'none'}); });
```

How can I return it (`background:#fff url(img.png)`)  by click event of another div (for example : `#return-bg`)

```
$('#return-bg').click(function (){
        //?????
}
```

Comment: `$('#bg').css({'background':'#fff url(img.png)'});`??

Comment: That looks like CSS, not HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best way to handle it would be to define another css rule and use add/remove class.

CSS:

```css
#bg.nobg{
    background: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```js
$('#remove-bg').click(function (){
   $('#bg').addClass('nobg'); 
});

$('#return-bg').click(function (){
    $('#bg').removeClass('nobg'); 
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8FFH/)**

Comment: Can the downvoter explain please... Or is it just a random sadistic downvote spree.

Answer (score 1):

Save it to variable and then use it when you want. Example

```
var before = $('#bg').css('background');

$('#remove-bg').click(function (){
   $('#bg').css({'background':'none'}); 
});

$('#return-bg').click(function (){
   $('#bg').css({'background': before }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the inline style (jQuery appends css from css() function as inline style):

```
$('#element').attr('style', '');
```

Small example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9RxvD/